# Changing RAM on windows with fast startup

Tags: memory, windows-11

I will have to add RAM to a bunch of PCs.

By default they are on fast startup, which I understand saves kernel and drivers info to a conf file to boot faster.

I would like to avoid booting them up, disabling the option, and shut them down, before loading them again to enable it again.

But wouldn't this cause an issue, since I'm changing some of the hardware?

Comment: Soon I'll be able to test this but I want to plan the workload before Soon I'll be able to test this but I want to plan the workload before I get my hand on a test pc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If the RAM is compatible, modern versions of Windows are usually able to reconfigure themselves without user intervention. As you state, it is a good idea to perform a *full* shutdown, turning off Fast Startup in BIOS, before installing RAM. You might want to change pagefile size, or not. Test on *one* PC to establish an efficient routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At worst removing or upgrading the RAM will invalidate the contents of RAM and cause Windows to revert back to the hibernation data stored on a previous shutdown.

When windows loads from that hibernation file it will detect that something has changed in the system and that the hibernation data is invalid.

Then the system will tell you as much and then proceed to reboot and start from scratch.

You do not need to disable fastboot to change or upgrade the RAM. You *can* but at worst you lose that kernel hibernation data, which will be largely irrelevant as the system will simply reload it on properly booting again.

I would simply replace the RAM, boot the system to make sure it is all good, then carry on as you normally would.

---

Alternatively if you do want to replace the RAM and the system is running you can bypass the system saving data for fast boot running

```
shutdown /s /t 0
```

Which will not save any data to the hibernation file and will instead perform an "old" normal system shutdown.

That way you do not need to disable fastboot, you effectively disable it for a single shutdown by using the command line and the computer will perform a proper startup next time it is booted.